# Developed by link on homepage but not on content pages

Tags: seo, google, links

I've been discussing this with peers recently and the general outcome was that for SEO purposes you should have your created and designed by links etc as links only on the homepage. Then for content pages (basically anything other than the homepage) you should remove the link as Google sees that as duplicate content.

Essentially it's detected as a spam-related link because there are lots of pages all with the same link back to another website. I haven't seen this done anywhere from memory and wanted some feedback as to what the general rule of thumb was when it comes to vanity links. Any answers are much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You may [find my answer helpful](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77120/20604).

Comment: With respect, the linked answer in the comment is misleading. It refers to and effect of *not having been caught*. With search engines you have to remember that there are sometimes two parts to the process; a trigger and effect. Not all Google algorithms operate all the time. Some are quarterly or periodic. Many of these rely upon triggers. Just because something works on one site, does not mean it will continue to work or will work for everybody. A threshold must be reached before a trigger is set, then the quarterly updates will kick in and then a drop in the SERPs.